# SQL select specific (4th) part of column BLOB data, separated by specific pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

There is a BLOB column that contains data like:

```
{{Property1 {property1_string}} {Property2 {property2_string}} {Property3 {property3_string}} {Property4 {property4_string}} {Property5 {property5_string}}}
```

I select the above column to display the BLOB data, as follows:

```
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(blobColumn))
```

I need to display only the data of 4th Property of BLOB column, so the following:
{Property4 {property4_string}}

So, I need help to create the necessary select for this purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select substr(cast(blobfieldname as 
varchar2(2000)),instr(cast(blobfieldname as 
varchar2(2000)),'{',1,8)),instr(cast(blobfieldname as 
varchar2(2000)),'}',1,8))- 
instr(cast(blobfieldname as varchar2(2000)),'{',1,8))) from tablename;
```

Comment: Property1, Property2, etc. can be totally different attribute values, like for example: Property1 be "Number", Property2 be "FirstName", Property 3 be "LastName", Property4 be "TextDescription", etc., so variable length, not fixed. Same stands for the strings of those properties, they are of variable length, not fixed length, containing different info, too.  So, I am afraid that with what you provided you check for fixed length 8 fields(?), so it will not work.  Please correct me if I am wrong and I did not understand well.   Thank you.

Comment: no 8 stands for 8th occurences for '{' and '}' did you run the query is it showing output??

Answer (score 0):

You may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'[^{} ]+', 1, 2 * :n) FROM t;
```

Where n is the nth property string you want to extract from your data.

```
n = 1 gives property1_string
n = 2 gives property2_string 
..
and so on
```

Note that `s` should be  the output of `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2`

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=13ac20db4e63d71d976eb442035b4ec1)